# Using Redis with Rails 4.2.0 Problems, Can't run rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I'm having problems running redis on a simple, standard rails application.  I added redis to my Gemfile:

```
1  source 'https://rubygems.org'                                                                                                                                         
2                                                                                                                                                                       
3  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'                                                                                                                                        
4  gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'                                                                                                                                              
5  gem 'jquery-rails'                                                                                                                                                    
6  gem 'pg'                                                                                                                                                              
7  gem 'rails', '4.2.0'                                                                                                                                                  
8  gem 'redis'                                                                                                                                                           
9  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'                                                                                                                                            
10 gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc                                                                                                                                   
11 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
```

I then bundle installed, and add config/initializers/redis.rb:

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => 'localhost', :port => 6379)
```

When I went to run rails console I came up with this error.

```
/home/adam/dev/Sandbox/Redis/config/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>': Redis is not a module (TypeError)
    from /home/adam/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require'
    from /home/adam/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /home/adam/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
    from /home/adam/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/adam/.gem/ruby/2.1.5/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure how to fix this and would be appreciative for some help.

Comment: Which version of ``redis`` gem is getting installed (check that on Gemfile.lock)?

Comment: It works now, I'm not sure why it was creating this error.

Comment: Probably Spring